# Invoking the print/save/email function of Adobe Reader plugin in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex, acrobat, adobe-reader

I am looking for a way to invoke the print/save/email functions from the Adobe Reader plugin in the browser. To better explain, please open the following image in your browser:

http://stylephp.com/demo/pdf.png

In the image, you'll see a sample PDF is loaded in the browser in the Adobe Reader plugin. And the plugin has the save/email/print buttons on it. Also, there are four similar html buttons on top of it.

When clicked on the html buttons on top, I would like to invoke the button within the plugin.

FYI, I am using asp.net c# 2005.

Answer (score 2):

The Adobe Reader plugin does not expose any external Javascript API.