# save/print pdf embedded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have 2 external buttons which will be printing and saving an embedded pdf on the page. After a couple of hours searching on google I couldnt find any helpful to solve this. I know that the embedded object has buttons to print and save, but the client wants it with 2 outside buttons. I'll appreciate any help you can give me, thnx.

This is how I have the pdf

```
<div class="test">
 <embed src="embedded.pdf" width="300" height="175" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like this is possible for all browser due to security concerns. Please take a look at [Invoking the print/save/email function of Adobe Reader plugin in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394848/invoking-the-print-save-email-function-of-adobe-reader-plugin-in-browser) for further explanation.

However, it may be possible with ActiveX in IE, see [Silent print a embedded PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975652/silent-print-a-embedded-pdf).